MS Word method Application.CheckGrammar() not working
Environment: Office 2021 under Windows 11
The MS Word method Application.CheckGrammar() is supposed to return a Boolean for whether the string given to it is grammatically correct. However, I am getting true from it whether the string is correct or not. Here is a session in the immediate window of Word VBA:
? Application.CheckGrammar("I gone home.")
True
? Application.CheckGrammar("I went home.")
True

What could be causing this misbehavior? Can it be fixed?

On my side using Word 365, Debug.Print Application.CheckGrammar("I gone home.") shows False.

Is it possible that the method just doesn't work in Office 2021? Seems unlikely.
